# A bounded set E of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Jordan measurable then its set of boundary points has outer content zero.

Tags: measure-theory

I am new to measure Theory and I read Books and papers about measure theory and dealing with this problem in early and try to prove it but I can't.

Please give a elementary proof for this.

Comment: I don't think so. It is theorem in books.

Comment: If you are learning Measure Theory on your own I would advise you to skip Jordan measure , content etc and straightaway learn the subject from a  standard Measure Theory  book. Jordan measure is restrictive. (I just discovered that a fat Cantor set is not Jordan measuarble).

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I will skip. Should I start from Lebesgue measure. I start with Real Analysis by bruckner. skip first chapter(preface).

Comment: Yes, you can start with Lebesgue measure.